# Expression Language & Eclipse warning: "items" does not support runtime expressions

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, el

i have the following JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><c:out value="${it.title}"/></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:forEach var="speaker" items="${it.speakers}" varStatus="stat">
            <ul>
                <li><c:out value="${speaker.person.firstName}" /> <c:out value="${speaker.person.lastName}" />, <c:out value="${speaker.person.address.city.zip}" /> <c:out value="${speaker.person.address.city.name}" /></li>
            </ul> 
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eclipse warns me about every instance of EL Expressions in my code:

```
Warning [line 10]: "value" does not support runtime expressions
Warning [line 13]: "items" does not support runtime expressions
...
```

this is however not true, EL gets evaluated correctly by the server.

Can anyone hint me in the right direction why eclipse is warning me about those EL expressions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your taglib directive imports a JSTL 1.0 taglib. It should be JSTL 1.1 instead (note the difference in URI):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: And ensure that web.xml is declared as at least Servlet 2.4

Comment: @BalusC I am getting this exception and it seems to be related to your comment : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Can you help what I need to do?

Comment: Also appropriate jstl library should be added: jstl-1.2.jar instead of jstl.jar and standard.jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257677/why-jstl-number-format-value-does-not-support-runtime-expressions

Comment: Thanks.. this worked for me. Is there a way to add the line `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> ` by default to all JSP files?

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution ([found here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)):

> **Twin Libraries**
>
> The JSTL tag libraries come in two
>   versions which differ only in the way
>   they support the use of runtime
>   expressions for attribute values.
>
> In the JSTL-RT tag library,
>   expressions are specified in the
>   page's scripting language. This is
>   exactly how things currently work in
>   current tag libraries.
>
> In the JSTL-EL tag library,
>   expressions are specified in the JSTL
>   expression language. An expression is
>   a String literal in the syntax of the
>   EL.
>
> When using the EL tag library you
>   cannot pass a scripting language
>   expression for the value of an
>   attribute. This rule makes it possible
>   to validate the syntax of an
>   expression at translation time.

So maybe your eclipse and the server use different tag libraries.

Answer (score 2):

try this:
change this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
```

to yes:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
```

hope it works for you. I got this from www.csdn.net.

Comment: This is absolutely not the **right** solution. The proposed URI is from the JSTL "prototype" version. You should upgrade to *at least* JSTL 1.1. See also axtavt's answer and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info