# Why JSTL number format value does not support runtime expressions?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have this code:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" 
                  maxFractionDigits="2" 
                  value="${maxAllowableAmount}" />
```

I have this warning in Eclipse editor:

> "value" does not support runtime expressions

I tried to ignore it and run the app, but I have this runtime error:

> quote symbol expected

How am I gonna deal with this?

My data comes from the database and I want to format it on my browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the prehistoric JSTL 1.0 version (or even a prototype). You need to upgrade to at least JSTL 1.1, or if your container supports it (Servlet 2.5 or newer), upgrade to currently latest JSTL 1.2.

You can find JSTL download links in our [JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Don't forget to remove the old JSTL libraries (`jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`) and to fix the `@taglib` declarations to include the `/jsp` path. Also ensure that your `web.xml` is declared conform at least Servlet 2.4 for JSTL 1.1 or as at least Servlet 2.5 for JSTL 1.2.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

Ensure that you are using the correct `@ taglib` directive. Replace:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
```

with:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
```

The `/jsp` makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need an RT/EL version of the tag library.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html#wp67593

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit peculiar.  If I understand the [taglib javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) correctly, the `type` attribute can be a runtime value.

Perhaps you are using an older version of JSTL that doesn't support RT/EL?  Check what namespace is associated with the 'fmt' prefix in your JSP.