# Cannot find the JSTL core library descriptor error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, taglib

I am getting following error:

[image]

The taglib declaration I have:

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Also I have included jstl.jar in my project libraries folder as can be seen above. So what could be other possible reasons.

Comment: What does content assist offer for the URI attribute value?  Depending on the version in that jar, it may be different.  It actually looks like you're using a valid URI just 2 lines down.

Comment: I am trying above URI since I initially stuck up with error asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530994/expression-language-eclipse-warning-items-does-not-support-runtime-expressi) and solution asks for this new URI, where can I download the JAR having this taglib, please help since I am not getting any reply

Comment: I just tried jstl-1.2.jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl12jar.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Drop all the directives you currently have in your JSP file, and drop the `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`.
2. Download the last JAR of JSTL [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar), and put it in your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.
3. Use the following URI in your **taglib** directives.

Directive for JSTL Core:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: yeah I was older version of JSTL, latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was removing the "/jsp" from uri:

"<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>"

In my case, I also had to change the "jstl/core" to "jstl/core_rt"

Regards.

Comment: This "solution" only allows you to keep using your old version of JSTL. You should upgrade, as far as I can remember there are no backward compatibility issues, only improvements.